# Prove that $\sqrt{n} > \ln n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove that $\sqrt{n} > \ln n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I need to use this fact for one of the proofs that I am working on. However, I am having trouble proving this. I tried induction but don't really know how to do it. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 17):

The most important inequality about the exponential is
$$\tag1e^x\ge 1+x\qquad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\text{ with equality iff }x=0.$$
From this we find 
$$\tag2 e^{x}=(e^{x/2})^2\stackrel{(a)}\ge (1+x/2)^2=(1-x/2)^2+2x\stackrel{(b)}\ge 2x$$
where $(a)$ holds for $x\ge-2$ and is strict for $x\ne0$, and $(b)$ is strict for $x\ne 2$. Hence $e^{x}>2x$ at least for $x\ge-2$ and in fact trivially from $2x<0<e^x$ also for $x<-2$.
By squaring $e^{2x}>4x^2$ for all $x\ge 0$, i.e. 
$$\tag3 e^x>x^2\qquad\text{for all }x\ge0.$$
With $x=\sqrt n>0$ and taking logarithms on both sides we get
$$ \sqrt n>\ln n\qquad\text{for all }n>0.$$

Comment: how to u get to 3? why e^2x becomes e^x?

Comment: Because since $e^{2x} > 4x^2 = 2x \cdot 2x = (2x)^2 $, then we can put $y = 2x$ and we obtain $e^y > y^2 $

Comment: I don't understand this post, in that sense that how do you prove the "important" inequality? I am presuming you just do what Dutta's post does, and differentiate...

Answer (score 10):

Consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt x - \log x$ and differentiate:
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt x} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\sqrt x - 2}{2x}.
$$
Hence $f'(x) \le0$ for all $0\lt x\le4$ and $f'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x \ge 4$. So the function is monotone decreasing for all $0\lt x \le 4$ and monotone increasing for all $x \ge 4$.

Also $f(4) = \sqrt 4 - \log4=2-2\log2=2\log(\mathrm e/2) > 0$.

Thus $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \gt0$, that is, $\sqrt x - \log x > 0$.

Now put $x = n $ and get your result.

Comment: Do you happen to know any non-calculus way of doing this? thanks

Comment: I do not know. Hope some other people will come with answer.

Comment: Actually $f$ is only increasing on $(4,+\infty)$, not on $(1,+\infty)$. Thus the argument can be saved, but it needs to be modified. // @upvoters Why the upvote?

Comment: @Dutta Please correct the second line $\frac{\sqrt{x}-\color{red}{2}}{2x}$

Comment: @derivative Thank you for identifying it. My mistake and same mistake has done by many people.

Comment: @did please downvote. They have done mistake like me.

Comment: Not interested in downvoting your answer (sorry to disappoint you). No, most probably "they" have not "made a mistake like you", simply "they" neither read carefully nor tried to really understand--which is what I am objecting to.

Comment: The argument can be saved by noting that $f(4)=2-2\log2\gt0$ (since $2\lt\mathrm e$ hence $\log2\lt1$). Thus $f\gt0$ everywhere, as needed to conclude. (But, alas, I fail to see how $f(1)\gt0$ yields what you say.)

Comment: Right, once one knows that $f(4)\gt0$, the part "For n=1,2 and 3, compute" is not needed.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = 2 \frac{\ln(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}},$$ so it is sufficient to show that $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}< \frac{1}{2} \ \text{for all} \ x >0 \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

If $f(x)= \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ then $f'(x)= \frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}$, so $f$ is nondecreasing on $(0,e]$ and nonincreasing on $[e,+ \infty)$. Therefore, $f$ has a global maximum at $x=e$. Because $f(e)= \frac{1}{e} < \frac{1}{2}$, $(1)$ may be deduced.

Answer (score 4):

let $\sqrt n > \ln n$, then 
$$\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{(\log n)^2-( \log(n+1))^2+( \log(n+1))^2+1}> \log (n+1) $$
hence proved by induction, that is if we show that
$$\log(n)^2 - \log(n+1)^2 + 1 > 0$$
which you can find the [maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20log%28x%2b1%29%5E2%20-%20log%28x%29%5E2%20for%20x%3E0) using calculus which is less than $1$. Also you can try this,
\begin{align*}
\log(n+1)^2 - \log(n)^2 &= (\log n + \log(1 +1/n))^2 - \log(n)^2\\ 
 &= 2 \log(1 + 1/n) \log n+ \log(1+1/n)^2\\ 
 &\le 2 \left( \frac 1 n  \right ) \log n +\left( \frac 1 n \right )^2\\ 
 & < 2 \left( \frac 1 n  \right ) \sqrt n +\left( \frac 1 n \right )^2 \\
 & <1 \;  \forall n>5
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

For any $n\geq 1$, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ($\text{CS}$),

$$ \log n=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}\color{red}{\stackrel{\text{CS}}{\leq}}\sqrt{\int_{1}^{n}dx\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^2}}=\sqrt{(n-1)\left(1-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)}=\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$